# How do I find an Index of a header in a csv file in Python?

Tags: python

My program list the headers of a CSV file to a user and asks him to pick an x and an y to plot. It works fine, but I don't want the user to type out the header string. I would rather find the index of each of the header and ask him to type a number instead. My csv file looks as follows:

```
time(s),speed(m/s),alt_a(m),....
25,62,10
45,70,20
30,50,30
```

Currently, the user has to type out for x, speed(m/s) I would rather the data shows up something like this and have the user just type 2.

```
1.time(s),2.speed(m/s),3.alt_a(m)
```

I looked a lot during the past two days and I can't seem to find any information of how would I even begin to do this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data.csv',index_col=False)

while True:
    print (list(df))
    print ('Select X-Axis')
    xaxis = input()
    print ('Select Y-Axis')
    yaxis = input()
    break

df.plot(x= xaxis, y= yaxis1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the header with `df.columns`,

```
print(", ".join(["{0}.{1}".format(i,x) for i,x in enumerate(df.columns)]))
x_index = input("index of the x series:")
x_header = df.columns[x_index]
y_index = input("index of the y series:")
y_header = df.columns[y_index]
df.plot(x= x_header , y= y_header )
```

the first line creates a list of the headers in the format you specified `1.time(s),2.speed(m/s),3.alt_a(m)` and prints it.

`"{0}.{1}".format(i,x)` creates a string in the format "i.x" where i is a counter and x is an element of the headers

The second line asks an input to the user, which would be the index `0,1,2..` in accordance to the previous list.

In the third line, `df.columns[x_index]` is the header that the user chose.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit on the code? what does it exactly do? and what is in raw_input? Sorry I am very new to python.

Comment: OP is using python 3, it would likely be less confusing if your example does the same!

Comment: @JMat I ran the code, however, it gave me this error: IndexError: too many indices for array.

Comment: @JMat I did a little playing around and I noticed that if I enter a single digit it works, so let say between 0-9 when I try an element between 10-50 it gives me that error.

Comment: @J.Jones replace `input("...")` by `int(input("..."))` to force python to read your input as an integer and not a string